# Max no of simultaneous active sessions for a single user

Tags: users, login

Is there any limitation to log in with multiple devices simultaneously using a single subscriber (user) account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. WordPress login "sessions" are cookie-based and work on each device as if they were the only one in existence.